# What's the best way to save a users selection

Tags: cookies

I'm wondering if cookies is the best way to save a users selection/inputs on a web page? Or is there a better alternative? As I think you have to put a warning now if you use cookies.
So a user goes to a web page makes a selelection goes away from the page and then comes back a few days later and their selections are remembered. 
I don't want them to have to sign in. 
I think it would need to use cookies but thought I would ask. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as you already mentioned that you don't want that the user needs to log in you can only use cookies (or localestorage)

But a cookie is not unique, e.g. User A makes selection and you save it in a cookie then if User B which uses the same Browser on the same machine has the same value.

Alternatively you could also use localestorage but this is not provided in older internet explorer versions. Which has the same characteristic as a cookie **basically**

Best regards